# Filling javascript array with key + value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on an app that uses an html/javascript framework.
The app loads in pages from a database using a PHP script and a $.get call whenever a page is shown like so:

```
    // Set lastTime var for counting the amount of time passed since $.get
    var lastTime = 0;

    // Amount of minutes before new $.get
    var timeOut = 1;

    // Cache
    var cache = [];

    function load_page(page, location) {
        // Check if 1 minute passed
        if ( Math.floor((new Date() - lastTime)/60000) < timeOut ) {
            // Get cache
            $(location+' .homeText').html(cache[page]);
        } else {
            // Get URL
            $.get('http://mydomain.com/get_posts.php?page='+page, function(data) {          
                $(location+' .homeText').html(data);
            });

            // Fill array with data
            cache.push();

            // Set lastTime var for checking how long since URL fetch
            lastTime = new Date();
        }
    }
```

It's almost done but I can't figure out how to populate my `cache` variable.
I want to populate it in such a way that I can use the `page` variable as a key to keep everything as dynamic as possible. I know how to fill an array with data but I can't figure out how to give it a specific key and value.

Comment: Do you have a sample/format of data (as returned by $.get() )?

Comment: it should be `cache.push(data);`

Comment: @user3558931 That's kinda difficult, since the result is from a post in wordpress. In the end it's just text within paragraph tags though.

Comment: @AamirAfridi But then it would have keys like `0`, `1` and `2` instead of the `page` variable as a key.

Comment: just use cache = data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, most people will use a simple Object to mimic the behavior of an associative array.

First, change your `cache` definition to be an empty object:

```
// Cache
var cache = {};
```

Then when you want to save your loaded HTML, just do this:

```
cache[page] = data;
```

Now, although you don't specify, I think you also have a bug in your logic -- you only have one `lastTime` variable, but I would think you would be keeping a 1 minute timer separately for each potential page load. In that case, you might have something more like this:

```
cache[page] = {
  html: data,
  expires: new Date().getTime() + 60000
};
```

To make it clear, here's how I might rewrite your function snippet, using the `cache` object to store both the HTML data and the time the data should expire.

```
// Cache
var cache = [];

function load_page(page, location) {
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Check for a previously cached value
  var result = cache[page];

  if (result && result.expires > now) {
    // Use the cached HTML data
    $(location + ' .homeText').html(result.data);
  } else {
    // Get URL
    $.get('http://mydomain.com/get_posts.php?page=' + page, function (data) {
      $(location + ' .homeText').html(data);

      // Store the HTML and its expiration time
      cache[page] = {
        data: data,
        expires: now + 60000
      };
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually had to switch the accepted answer. I ran into this bug just now and didn't know how to solve it. 10/10 on going the extra mile.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
var cache = {};
```

To get from cache

```
if (cache[page] !== undefined) {...
```

To populate the cache

```
cache[page] = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such things as an associative array in JavaScript.
[Here](http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/associative-arrays-in-javascript/) is an interessting blog post about that : [http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/...](http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/associative-arrays-in-javascript/)

But you can do this thought :

cache.push({key:value,key:value});

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if for any reason you had to use an array `cache` then you would use the following:

```
// Set lastTime var for counting the amount of time passed since $.get
var lastTime = 0;

// Amount of minutes before new $.get
var timeOut = 1;

// Cache
var cache = [];

function load_page(page, location) {
    // Check if 1 minute passed
    if ( Math.floor((new Date() - lastTime)/60000) < timeOut ) {
        // Get cache
        $(location+' .homeText').html(cache[page]);
    } else {
        // Get URL
        $.get('http://mydomain.com/get_posts.php?page='+page, function(data) {          
            $(location+' .homeText').html(data);

            // Fill array with data
            var oPage = {};
            oPage[ page ] = data;
            cache.push( oPage );

            // Set lastTime var for checking how long since URL fetch
            lastTime = new Date();

        });
    }
}
```